# Projects in their infancy (read: too much changes) and version control

Tags: git, version-control

I wonder what is the best practice for managing projects in their infancy stage?  Let me explain what I mean.

Recently I started a new project which deals with languages and technologies I am not familiar with. As a result there are tons of changes made each day. In fact it not so uncommon I find myself with a completely different project structure and half the code rewritten by the end of day.
Using version control at this point seems almost like a waste of effort. Figuring what to write in a commit messages alone got me a few gray hairs.

So... what do you guys do in such situations (assuming you don't need to share the project with anyone else at this stage)?
Wait till the project stabilizes and then put it under version control or hope that later no one notices the dozens of meaningless *"reimplemented everything"* commit messages?

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please also consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not sharing your project with anyone yet, don't worry about your commits and how messy they are, you can always squash them later with an interactive rebase to clean them up before you share your code with others:

```
git rebase -i <base-commit>
```

In the rebase TODO list, add `s` (for "squash") next to each commit you want to squash into the previous one, or `f` (for "fixup") to do the same thing, but reuse the commit message of the previous commit instead of combining them:

```
pick e953225 Add meow meow meow
s def892d Add dogs (WOOF WOOF!)
s c8321e2 Add foobar.txt
s ecb173c Modify foobar.txt
```

You can read more about [squashing commits from the **FREE online Pro Git book**](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-4.html#Squashing-Commits).

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are changing things so completely at this point, the easiest way might be to ZIP or TAR the whole tree structure of your development directories each day, and place that file into version control.  It's not very efficient, but it allows you to go back to a previous effort after something goes terribly wrong.  You should still try to include a version.txt file that you can review to ensure that you find the right "starting point" if reconstructing past work.

Comment: Version controlling compressed archive files of source code seems counterproductive. Why not simply version control the source itself?